# How to protect swagger endpoint in .NET Core API?

Tags: c#, api, swagger, asp.net-core-2.0, swagger-ui

I have an api build in .net core 2.1. To restrict access to various endpoints, I use IdentityServer4 and [Authorize] attribute. However, my goal during development is to expose the api swagger documentation to our developers so that they may use it no matter where they work from. The challenge that I face is how do I protect the swagger index.html file so that only they can see the details of the api.

I have created a custom index.html file in the wwwroot/swagger/ui folder and that all works, however, that file uses data from `/swagger/v1/swagger.json` endpoint which is not protected. I would like to know how can I override the return value for that specific endpoint so that I may add my own authentication to it?

EDIT:

Currently, I have achieved the above with the following middleware:

```
public class SwaggerInterceptor
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SwaggerInterceptor(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var uri = context.Request.Path.ToString();
        if (uri.StartsWith("/swagger/ui/index.html"))
        {
            var param = context.Request.QueryString.Value;

            if (!param.Equals("?key=123"))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("{\"result:\" \"Not Found\"}", Encoding.UTF8);
                return;
            }
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

public class Startup 
{
    //omitted code

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<SwaggerInterceptor>();
        //omitted code
    }
}
```

What I don't like about this approach as it will inspect every single request. Is there a better way to achieve this? The above only protects the index.html file, but I can adjust it to protect the json endpoint in the similar fashion.

Comment: Notes: Inspecting every single request is a very "cheap" operation.

Also, anyone looking to do with with Swashbuckle and OpenIdConnect see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65094653/6795110

Comment: Also see discussion at [How to restrict access to swagger/* folder?](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/384)

Answer (score 6):

You can choose some options:

- basic authorization
- OpenId Connect authorization using identity server

#### Basic Authorization

In this case you just close your swagger endpoints.

```cs
// Startup.cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddScheme<BasicAuthenticationOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("Basic", _ => {});
        ...  
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            ...
            
            var pipeline = endpoints.CreateApplicationBuilder().Build();
            var basicAuthAttr = new AuthorizeAttribute { AuthenticationSchemes = "Basic" };
            endpoints
                .Map("/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json", pipeline)
                .RequireAuthorization(basicAuthAttr);
            endpoints
                .Map("/swagger/index.html", pipeline)
                .RequireAuthorization(basicAuthAttr);
        });
    }
}

// BasicAuthenticationHandler.cs
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<BasicAuthenticationOptions>
{
    ...
}
```

#### OIDC Authorization Using IdentityServer4

I have written the article for this case: https://medium.com/dev-genius/csharp-protecting-swagger-endpoints-82ae5cfc7eb1

Answer (score 2):

Here it is using OpenIdConnect and Swashbuckle in Asp.Net Core 3.1.  Now, if I type https://myurl.com/swagger I get routed to my normal login page and after logging in successfully, I can see the swagger.

```
public class Startup
{ 
    //<snip/>

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    { 
      //<snip/>

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "Some name"); });

        app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
        {
            var pipeline = routes.CreateApplicationBuilder().Build();
            
            routes.Map("/swagger", pipeline).RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute {AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme});
            routes.Map("/swagger/index.html", pipeline).RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute {AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme});
            routes.Map("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", pipeline).RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute { AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme });
            routes.Map("/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json", pipeline).RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute { AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme });

            routes.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
     }
}
```

EDIT:
<s>Somehow I thought the below was working, but when I retested it later it turned out that actually it was giving error: The request reached the end of the pipeline without executing the endpoint. So, I changed to include a fixed set of endpoints under /swagger that contain afaik the key data.</s>

routes.Map("/swagger/{**any}", pipeline).RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute {AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme});

Note: this {**any} part of the route template protects all files under /swagger as well, so for example /swagger/index.html, /swagger/v1/swagger.json etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best option is what you already did. Build your own middleware, as I don't know any middleware for validate authentication on static files. You could add the basePath to avoid enter at this specific middleware when its not necessary. Like the code below

```
app.Map("/swagger", (appBuilder) =>
{
    appBuilder.UseMiddleware<SwaggerInterceptor>();
});
```

Also this article could help you to build a more generic middleware for validate authentication on static files.
https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/06/authorization-policies-and-middleware-in-asp-net-5.aspx

Comment: above link broken

Answer (score 1):

After some search I solved and it works for me.
you must define a middle-ware class to authenticate the user whom wants to visit your swagger-ui view page like this.

```
public class SwaggerBasicAuthMiddleware
{
private readonly RequestDelegate next;
public SwaggerBasicAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
{
  this.next = next;
}
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
  {
   if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger"))
   {
    string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic "))
    {
     // Get the credentials from request header
     var header = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);
     var inBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(header.Parameter);
     var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inBytes).Split(':');
     var username = credentials[0];
     var password = credentials[1];
     // validate credentials
     if (username.Equals("Test") && password.Equals("Test"))
     {
      await next.Invoke(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
      return;
     }
    }
    context.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = "Basic";
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
   }
   else
   {
    await next.Invoke(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
   }
  }
 }
```

For simplicity I am using hardcoded credentials but same can enhanced to use it from database also.

Also I have to create a extension method in a static class like this

```
public static class AuthorizedSampleClass
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerAuthorized( this IApplicationBuilder builder )
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<SwaggerBasicAuthMiddleware>( );
    }
}
```

in startup.cs remove the env.IsDevelopment() part and add app.UseSwaggerAuthorized( ); right before app.UseSwagger( ); because authentication middleware will be called before accessing swagger ui.

```
app.UseSwaggerAuthorized( );
app.UseSwagger( );
app.UseSwaggerUI( c => c.SwaggerEndpoint( "/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Broker.Rest v1" ) );
```

now press F5 and rout to swagger view, it has done.
press "Test" and "Test" as username and password to enter.