# How control access to swagger doc in .NET Core?

Tags: .net, api, swagger, swagger-ui

I ran swagger in .NET Core and hit `https://url/swagger/index.html` in the browser and saw the program documentation.

The problem is that anyone can access my program document by entering the above URL into a browser.

How can I restrict people's access to the document?

Comment: What's so bad about anyone accessing your program's documentation?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://stackoverflow.com/q/55199383/1188513

Answer (score 1):

I had written a detail article with complete solution for same topic last year.
have a look

https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/securing-swagger-in-production-92d0a045a5

https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/securing-swagger-ui-in-production-in-asp-net-core-part-2-dc2ae0f03c73